# Multiply elements on Excel Macro

Tags: excel, vba

Goodevening,
with your help i can manage to multiply some elements on a right column with some other elements on a left column, but the elements on the left were seprated by blank cells.
What if there aren't blank space?

[image: table without space]

How can i do the condition in the cycle?
The previous code (with space) was this:    (Thank you)

```
Sub test()

Dim x As Integer
Dim y As Integer

Range("A1").Select
x = 1
y = 1

Do Until IsEmpty(ActiveCell) And IsEmpty(ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0))
        If IsEmpty(Cells(x, "A")) = True Then
            y = x + 1
        End If

        If IsEmpty(Cells(x, "A")) = False Then
            Cells(x, "E").Value = Cells(x, "A").Value * Cells(y, "D").Value
        End If

        x = x + 1

      ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
 Loop
End Sub
```

This is the result i would like to achive: (so, the first number on column D will be multiplied for every number on the left Until the number on the column D change, and so goes on till the end)

[image: Result]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a FYI, this could be done with a formula in `E1`:

```
=A1*LOOKUP(2,1/(D$1:D1<>""),D$1:D1)
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but i tried to copy that on an empty cell and return me that it isn't correct ...

Comment: @Ikigai, what language are you using?

Comment: Ehm, excuse my ignorance but it's on Excel, i guess it's VBA?

Comment: No, I actually meant your `LCID`, or rather language (code) you are using in Excel itself. The formula I wrote works and is not VBA syntax.

Comment: So you'd input `=A1*CERCA(2;1/(D$1:D1<>"");D$1:D1)` in `E1` and drag down. Again, just a formula and nothing to do with VBA.

Comment: WOW It works!!! Thank you very much Sir!!  could you please explain me how it works..?

Comment: @Ikigai, if it works you may consider to accept it as a working answer by clicking the checkmark to the left. If you are unfamiliar, please see the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to see how it works. I've also noticed you have recently asked a seperate question with a working answer. You may want to revisit that one and do the same.

Comment: Also, a nice explaination of the formula is given [here](https://exceljet.net/formula/get-value-of-last-non-empty-cell)

Comment: Done it! THank you